# Convert from DisplayObject to Sprite with Loader

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sprite

Do you know why this AS3 code works:

```
var loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/items/boing.png")));
var o:DisplayObject = addChild(loader);
o.x = 100;
o.y = 100;
```

But if I cast to sprite it doesn't work? Ie the sprite appears on (0, 0) instead of (100, 100):

```
var loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/items/boing.png"))
var o:Sprite = Sprite(addChild(loader));
o.x = 100;
o.y = 100;
```

How would I properly have a sprite instead of a DisplayObject?  I need some sprite's features (drag'n drop, useHandCursor...), yet I wish I could still use the very quick writing with the loader.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this to get the Bitmap on stage. If you want it as a Sprite I think the best and easiest way is to create a new Sprite in the completeHandler, and then attach the Bitmap to the newly created Sprite.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class TestMain extends Sprite {

    private var mLoader:Loader;

    public function TestMain() {
        mLoader = new Loader();
        mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        mLoader.load(new URLRequest("image.png"));
    }

    private function completeHandler(event : Event) : void {
        var bmp:Bitmap = mLoader.content as Bitmap;
        bmp.x = 100;
        bmp.y = 100;

        addChild(bmp);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not casting the AS3 way.

In AS3 there are two ways to cast:

> Sprite(obj)

and

> obj as Sprite

The first causes an error if obj is not a sprite. The second returns null if the obj is not a sprite

The first one is the one you should use here.

Comment: Sorry I was using Haxe cast in my example. I try with your first notation.